# Read only first character with scanf

Tags: c

I am trying to read only the first character of each line using scanf.

With this input:

> c FILE: myciel3.col
>
> c SOURCE: Michael Trick (trick@cmu.edu)
>
> c DESCRIPTION: Graph based on Mycielski transformation.
>
> c Triangle free (clique number 2) but increasing
>
> c coloring number
>
> p edge 11 20

Sorry for my bad english.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char option;
    int countC = 0;
    int countP = 0;
    while(scanf("%c",&option) != EOF) {
        if(option == 'c') countC++;
        else if (option == 'p') countP++;
    }
    printf("c: %d\tp: %d\n",countC, countP);
    return (0);
}
```

I expect the output C:5 and P:1, but the actual output is c:15 p:2

Comment: Is it a real name and email address? If so, it could be wise to anonymize them.

Comment: @Broman `scanf()` *can* return EOF.

Comment: Why not just use `getchar()`? `scanf()` is overkill for reading a single char at a time.

Comment: @Shawn I stand corrected. Was so sure it was always a non-negative value indicating the number of successful assignments, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code reads every character in your input, not the first character of each line.

Use `fgets` or any other function that gets a line.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char option[255];
    int countC = 0;
    int countP = 0;
    while(fgets(option, 255, stdin) != NULL) {
        if(option[0] == 'c') countC++;
        else if (option[0] == 'p') countP++;
    }
    printf("c: %d\tp: %d\n",countC, countP);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: A query. If now I want to get the two numbers of "p edge 11 20". 
else if (option[0] == 'p') {
            sscanf(option, "%d", &v);
        }

Comment: say there's `n1, n2` integer variable: `sscanf(option, "p edge %d %d", &n1, &n2);`